# React database update, transaction with JWT

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, jwt, transactions

I have a login page that redirects me to a user profile with JWT authentication. In the profile page, I have a form with a transaction that allows me to send money to another user. As u can see I need an amount and a bill number. So when I want to send money to another user it is fine. It works. The problem is when I want to deduct the amount in a current user. The decodedToken shows the updated amount but not update into the database. Any tips??

JWT update if thats the issue.

```js
     const SendMoney = async (req, res) => {
      try {
      const { token } = req.cookies;
      const { amount, billnumber } = req.body;

      jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {}, async (err, decodedToken) => {
      const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id).populate("bills");
      const targetBill = await Bill.findOne({ billnumber });
      if (!targetBill) {
        return res.json({ error: "Invalid checknumber!" });
      }

      // Update the amount for the target bill
      targetBill.amount += parseFloat(amount);

      if (Array.isArray(user.bills) && user.bills.length > 0) {
        user.bills[0].amount -= parseFloat(amount);
      }

      // Save the changes to the database

      await Promise.all([targetBill.save()]);
      await user.save();

      return res.json({
        success: "Tranzaction successfull!",
        decodedToken, // just for check
        user,
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: "Server error!",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Before subtracting money from current user where r u checking if user has enough funds? and i unable to comprehend your question, can u simplify it?

Comment: Im not checking the amounts in the bills bcs I can edit manually if it nesesarry. I have a form that need an amount and a billnumber to the tranzaction. When this function is over the amount is added to the user who owns the bill (billnumber) (toUser) but not deduct the amount the logged user (fromUser). fromUser is who logged in to his profile, toUser is who get the money (for the reference, these are not in the code). Im hope is helping in the question.